# Error while trying to implement Google SignIn

Tags: php, google-signin

I'm trying to add Google SignIn to [my website](http://barreeeiroo.ga/), but I can't see anythig, but if I see de Page Source Code, I see this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function createAuthUrl() on a non-object in **/home/u289995868/public_html/es/php/glogin/app/classes/GoogleAuth.php** on line **26**

The code of this file:

```
<?php 
class GoogleAuth
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Google_Client $googleClient = null)
    {
        $this->client = $googleClient;

        if($this->client)
        {
            $this->client->setClientId('xxxxxxxx');
            $this->client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxx');
            $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://barreeeiroo.ga/es/php/glogin/index.php');
            $this->client->setScopes('email');
        }
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    public function getAuthUrl()
    {
        return $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    }
}
?>
```

Index.php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/init.php';
$googleClient = new Google_Client();
$auth = new GoogleAuth();
?>

... Here there is some code for navbar and other, not important

<h1>Prueba de Login de Google</h1>
<?php if(!$auth->isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>">Iniciar Sesión</a>
<?php else: ?>
    Ya has iniciado sesión            
<?php endif; ?>
```

*If you want to see the error, go to [this website](http://barreeeiroo.ga/es/php/glogin/) and View Source Code*

Comment: Where are you instantiating the object? (The `$auth` variable definition)

Comment: EDIT: I've included right now to question, @FirstOne

Comment: Thanks @FirstOne
It works

Comment: Comments converted into an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change from

```
$auth = new GoogleAuth();
```

to

```
$auth = new GoogleAuth($googleClient);
```

---

If you check the constructor of `GoogleAuth`:

```
public function __construct(Google_Client $googleClient = null)
```

You'll see that it defaults to `null`. This means that if don't pass anything to the constructor, the `$googleClient` parameter will be `null`.

---

Quick [RDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging):

- {require and instantiate}
- create an instance of `GoogleAuth` passing no arguments and put the object into `$auth`;

  - since the parameter defaults to `null`, `$googleClient` is `null`;
  - set `GoogleAuth::$client` to be `$googleClient`'s value (so, `null`);
- {check stuff}
- call `GoogleAuth::getAuthUrl()`;

  - call `GoogleAuth::$client->createAuthUrl();` (Since `GoogleAuth::$client` is `null`, it's almost like you are calling `null->createAuthUrl()`;

That last step makes it easier to understand the error.